# iOS GDB Store output of examine register command to a variable

Tags: ios, gdb, jailbreak, mach

In iOS GDB I have this:

```
(gdb) x/s $r1
0x3154129c:  "_receivedStatusBarData:actions:"
```

How do I store the string `_receivedStatusBarData:actions:` to a variable like `$1` in GDB? Please advise thanks.

EDIT:

I think I found my answer, from [Delorie](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html), it mentioned that

> The addresses and contents printed by the x command are not saved in the value history because there is often too much of them and they would get in the way. Instead, GDB makes these values available for subsequent use in expressions as values of the convenience variables $_ and $__. After an x command, the last address examined is available for use in expressions in the convenience variable $_. The contents of that address, as examined, are available in the convenience variable $__.